# "The file access permissions do not allow the specified action" error in AIX

Tags: unix, file-permissions, aix

I want to give rights to all for an archive in my AIX system.

I do `chmod 777 myfle.tar` but when I connect with another user I have this message:

> The file access permissions do not allow the specified action.

How can I do this?

Comment: Reading right? Writing right? To give reading rights, from a terminal `chmod a+r filename`. [Link to some documentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod#Symbolic_modes). Check the output of `ls -ld myfle.tar`.

Comment: The typo about the filename is just in the question? And, which is the "specified action" which you are not allow to do?

Answer (score 5):

You probably need to give read and execution mode to the directory the file is on.

From [AIX File Permissions](http://www.cliffordweinmann.com/blog/2013/10/26/aix-file-permissions-102.html):

> - The **read** permission grants the ability to read a file. When set for a directory, this permission grants the ability to read the names
>     of files in the directory (but not to find out any further information
>     about them such as contents, file type, size, ownership, permissions,
>     etc.)
> - The **write** permission grants the ability to modify a file. When set for a directory, this permission grants the ability to modify
>     entries in the directory. This includes creating files, deleting
>     files, and renaming files.
> - The **execute** permission grants the ability to execute a file. This permission must be set for executable binaries (for example, a
>     compiled C++ program) or shell scripts (for example, a Perl program)
>     in order to allow the operating system to run them. When set for a
>     directory, this permission grants the ability to access file contents
>     and metainfo if its name is known, but not list files inside the
>     directory (unless read is set).